# Can you play Alien Swarm in 1st person?

Tags: alien-swarm

I guess Alien Swarm has been designed with 3rd person view in mind, but it would still be useful to try the 1st person view, if nothing else to help with friendly fire.

Is it possible, maybe as a toggle key? What files do I need to edit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have it indeed as a toggle-able key. In this example I'm using F7

First, you have to go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\alien swarm\swarm\cfg` and create an `autoexec.cfg` file. If it already exists, open it.

Then add these lines to the file:

```
sv_cheats 1
alias fps "firstperson;asw_hide_marine 1;asw_controls 0;bind F7 tps"
alias tps "thirdperson;asw_hide_marine 0;asw_controls 1;bind F7 fps"
bind F7 fps
```

Now you simply have to press <kbd>F7</kbd> to toggle between first person and third person.

By the way, there is no skybox, so the sky will simply be very white, and you can't do hacking in the first person. You'll have to toggle back if you're a Tech.

**Note:** *if the above path doesn't work, try replacing `Program Files (x86)` with `Program Files`.*

Comment: Note that there is no ceiling / sky. You may get some graphic errors.

Comment: wow, you really can do this? That's awesome

Comment: Just added that in right before I saw your comment.

Comment: It's a pity the fps lowers so drammatically...

Comment: For those interested, [here's a video of Alien Swarm being played in first person](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-erW8DAOEZg)