# Can you play L4D in 3rd person?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I want to play 'left 4 dead 2' pc game through third person view. Can I change the view by altering any settings?

Answer (score 11):

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/can-you-play-alien-swarm-in-1st-person/3275#3275) also works in L4D2, just it's the other way round.

Open this folder:

```
%PROGRAMFILES%\Steam\SteamApps\common\left 4 dead 2\left4dead2\cfg\
```

Create a file `autoexec.cfg` with the following contents:

```
alias fps "firstperson;bind F7 tps"
alias tps "thirdpersonshoulder;bind F7 fps"
bind F7 tps
```

<kbd>F7</kbd> will now toggle between first and over-the-shoulder third person mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by key bindings.

1. While in game, open up the console by pressing the backtick key (`). You have to enable the Developer Console first to do this. It's found under the Keyboard options.
2. Type bind X thirdpersonshoulder.
3. Hit return and close the close the console.

Now by pressing X your perspective should change, respectively. You can use any key for that matter, not just X.

Do take note that some sound effects might sound different, or not at all (for example, Shotguns).

Comment: That's a backtick...